# JavaScript count number of ocurrences in Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects and I was trying to figure out how I can create a new array of objects that would display a new array of objects, but with an "occurences" field.

Here is my starting json array of objects:

```
const fakeJson = [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-10",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-11",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "China"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  }
```

Example result of what I would like. Notice the for Country Canada, one of them has Occurences: 2 for Date_Available "2022-04-12". How would I be able to accomplish this?

```
const resultJSON = [
  {
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-10",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada",
    "Occurrences" : 1
  },
  {
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-11",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada",
    "Ocurrences" : 1
  },
  {
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada",
    "Occurrences" : 2
  },
  {
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "China",
    "Occurrences" : 1
  }
```

Here is what I have so far.  My idea was to create a temporary obj with the country name, date available and occurrence set default to 1. Then based on the Date_Available, increase by 1 every time it appeared. However, if China and Canada both have the same date, then it seems to mess up the code and does not properly print the result.

```
let countNameMapping = {};
let finalArr = [];

for(let i = 0; i < fakeJson.length; i++){
  let tempObj = {Country:fakeJson[i].Country, Date_Available: fakeJson[i].Date_Available, occurence: 1};
  let countryName = fakeJson[i].Country;
  let date = fakeJson[i].Date_Available;
  if(countNameMapping[date] === undefined){
    countNameMapping[countryName] = tempObj;
  } else {
    countNameMapping[date].occurence += 1;
  }
}

for(let k in countNameMapping){
  finalArr.push(countNameMapping[k])
}

console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/673707

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const json = fakeJson.reduce((prev, curr) => {
   const check = () => prev.findIndex(({ Date_Available, Country }) =>
      curr.Date_Available === Date_Available &&
      curr.Country === Country
   );

   check() === -1
         ? prev.push({
         ...Object.fromEntries(
              Object.entries(curr).filter(([key]) => !key.match(/id|name|age/i))
         ),
         Occurences: 1 })
         : prev[check()].Occurences++
   return prev
}, [])

console.log({ json });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) a custom key, eg `Date_Available + Country`
2. `reduce()` the result, create an array with the first object as base, then add `Ocurrences`, based on the amount of objects found (`.length`)

```js
const data = [{"Id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 32, "Date_Available": "2022-04-10", "Popularity": 99, "Country": "Canada"}, {"Id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 32, "Date_Available": "2022-04-11", "Popularity": 99, "Country": "Canada"}, {"Id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 32, "Date_Available": "2022-04-12", "Popularity": 99, "Country": "Canada"}, {"Id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 32, "Date_Available": "2022-04-12", "Popularity": 99, "Country": "China"}, {"Id": 1, "Name": "John", "Age": 32, "Date_Available": "2022-04-12", "Popularity": 99, "Country": "Canada"}];

const grouped = data.reduce((p, c) => {
    const key = c.Date_Available + c.Country;
    (p[key] = p[key] || []).push(c);
    return p;
}, {});

const result = Object.values(grouped).reduce((p, c) => [ ...p, { ...c[0], Ocurrences: c.length } ], []);

console.log(result)
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-10",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada",
    "Ocurrences": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-11",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada",
    "Ocurrences": 1
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada",
    "Ocurrences": 2
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "China",
    "Ocurrences": 1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `reduce` and `Object.values` for that

like this

```js
const groupBy = (data, ...keyGroup) => Object.values(data.reduce((res, item) => {
const key = keyGroup.map(k => item[k]).join('-')
 const existing = res[key] || {...item, occurencies: 0}
 return {
   ...res,
   [key]: {...existing,occurencies: existing.occurencies + 1 }
   
 }

}, {}))

const fakeJson = [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-10",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-11",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "China"
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "John",
    "Age": 32,
    "Date_Available": "2022-04-12",
    "Popularity": 99,
    "Country": "Canada"
  }
]

console.log('by ID', groupBy(fakeJson, 'Id'))
console.log('by Country', groupBy(fakeJson, 'Country'))
console.log('by country and date', groupBy( fakeJson, 'Country', 'Date_Available'))
```